# "ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis" when using `DataFrame.pct_change()` with frequencies greater than a day ('D')

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, valueerror

I have a DataFrame with hourly price data spanning two years. I'm using `DataFrame.pct_change()` to calculate percent returns over different time frequencies (hourly, daily, weekly, etc.). It works when I use `freq='H'`, `freq='D'` or any multiple of these (eg: `freq='7D'` or `freq='168H'`) but I get "ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis" when I try to use a frequency greater than a day like `freq='W'` or `freq='M'`.

Here are some screenshots:

[image: Sample of Data]
[image: Hourly Returns Work using <code>freq='H'</code>]
[image: 4-Hour Returns Work using <code>freq='4H'</code>]
[image: Daily Returns Work using <code>freq='D'</code>]
[image: Weekly Returns DON'T Work using <code>freq='W'</code>]
[image: Monthly Returns DON'T Work using <code>freq='M'</code>]

It doesn't make sense to me why the frequency parameters would stop working beyond daily ('D'). Any insight would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

PS: Here's the code:

```
"""freq=H: Calculates the returns of each row relative to 1 row(s) before."""
daily_data2016to2018_df.pct_change(freq='H').head()

"""freq=4H: Calculates the returns of each row relative to 4 row(s) before."""
daily_data2016to2018_df.pct_change(freq='4H').head(10)

"""freq=D: Calculates the returns of each row relative to 24 row(s) before."""
daily_data2016to2018_df.pct_change(freq='D').head(30)

"""freq=W: Calculates the returns of each row relative to 24*7 row(s) before."""
daily_data2016to2018_df.pct_change(freq='W').head(30)

"""I don't understand why frequencies greater than a day aren't working. 
I could see why frequencies less than an hour wouldn't work because
the data isn't that granular, but why not weekly, monthly, etc.?"""
daily_data2016to2018_df.pct_change(freq='M')
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are running into this error is you are making the jump from hourly calculations to calendar calculations. Hour works because your index is in hours. Day works because it is an absolute day, 24 hours. Week fails because it is looking for a calendar day and you have multiple days, hence the 'duplicate axis' error, which is telling you have multiple duplicate items, which you do, since it is looking for calendar days.

For example, if you try to use 'B' for business day, this will get the same duplicate axis error.

The simple work around is to use 7 days * 24 hours = 168 hours for a week.

```
# create dataframe
index = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=30000, freq='H')
data = np.random.rand(30000)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index, columns=['data'])

df['change'] = df.data.pct_change(freq='168H')
df.iloc[165:170, :]

                         data    change
2018-01-07 21:00:00  0.692558       NaN
2018-01-07 22:00:00  0.818543       NaN
2018-01-07 23:00:00  0.242034       NaN
2018-01-08 00:00:00  0.032420 -0.933596
2018-01-08 01:00:00  0.004672 -0.994401
```